# What are the various Buddhist scriptural designations and to what do they refer?

Tags: pali-canon, terminology, texts, tipitaka, scripture

In my readings so far (mostly Theravada based), I come across many scriptural references - for example, "AN," "MN 118," etc. To what do these designations refer? Is there some sort of concordance that summarizes the actual texts that these designations refer to?

Comment: Edit: Added some extra tags to your question to increase discoverability. Please roll-back if not suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They refer to various sutra collections within the [Tipitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka).

Like for example,

- [AN = Anguttara Nikaya](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/)
- [MN = Maddhiyama Nikaya](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/)

MN 118 would be the 118th sutta in the MN - which can be found in the MN index linked previously; or, Google is many times pretty helpful if you put in "MN 118 tipitaka" it should lead you to  http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html

> The Tipitaka (Pali ti, "three," + pitaka, "baskets"), or Pali canon,
>   is the collection of primary Pali language texts which form the
>   doctrinal foundation of Theravada Buddhism. The Tipitaka and the
>   paracanonical Pali texts (commentaries, chronicles, etc.) together
>   constitute the complete body of classical Theravada texts.
>
> The Pali canon is a vast body of literature: in English translation
>   the texts add up to thousands of printed pages. Most (but not all) of
>   the Canon has already been published in English over the years.
>   Although only a small fraction of these texts are available on this
>   website, this collection can be a good place to start.
>
> The three divisions of the Tipitaka are:
>
> ### Vinaya Pitaka
>
> The collection of texts concerning the rules of conduct
>   governing the daily affairs within the Sangha — the community of
>   bhikkhus (ordained monks) and bhikkhunis (ordained nuns). Far more
>   than merely a list of rules, the Vinaya Pitaka also includes the
>   stories behind the origin of each rule, providing a detailed account
>   of the Buddha's solution to the question of how to maintain communal
>   harmony within a large and diverse spiritual community.
>
> ### Sutta Pitaka
>
> The collection of suttas, or discourses, attributed to the Buddha and
>   a few of his closest disciples, containing all the central teachings
>   of Theravada Buddhism. (More than one thousand sutta translations are
>   available on this website.)
>   The suttas are divided among five nikayas
>   (collections):
>   Digha Nikaya — the "long collection"
>   Majjhima Nikaya —
>   the "middle-length collection"
>   Samyutta Nikaya — the "grouped
>   collection"
>   Anguttara Nikaya — the "further-factored collection"
>   Khuddaka Nikaya — the "collection of little texts":
>   Khuddakapatha
>   Dhammapada
>   Udana
>   Itivuttaka
>   Sutta Nipata
>   Vimanavatthu
>   Petavatthu
>   Theragatha
>   Therigatha
>   Jataka
>   Niddesa
>   Patisambhidamagga
>   Apadana
>   Buddhavamsa
>   Cariyapitaka
>   Nettippakarana (included only in the Burmese
>   edition of the Tipitaka)
>   Petakopadesa (  "   "  )
>   Milindapañha (  "  "  )
>
> ### Abhidhamma Pitaka
>
> The collection of texts in which the underlying doctrinal principles
>   presented in the Sutta Pitaka are reworked and reorganized into a
>   systematic framework that can be applied to an investigation into the
>   nature of mind and matter.

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/